# Hide registration and login buttons when a user logged in?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, show-hide

oK, since my original question didn't make sense to the majority, I will explain in details. I have a membership system I made through some tutorials based on codeigniter framework. on my main page I have 3 buttons containing login, register, forgot pass, respectively. when I test the login and enter my details as a user, I still can see the login button, which makes no sense because it should be hidden in case I logged in. The same thing for other features I mentioned above.

now I was trying some way like `if($_SESSION['user'] == "")
{` to achieve my goal, but without any success.

any idea how to do this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: ok, I made some update to the question. I guess now it is clear.

Comment: You guess wrong, this code does not contain the relevant code. We don't know how you flag that a user is logged in, so it's impossible to say how to react to that unknown quantity. This question is not clear.

Comment: it is fine, I made it through, and could solve it n my own. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div id='nav'> 
<?php

if(is_logged_in())
{
    if(is_admin())
    {
        echo anchor('admin','Admin Dashboard');
    }

    echo anchor('user/logout','Logout');
    echo anchor('users/profile','Profile' . '&nbsp;[' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . ']');

}
else
{
    echo anchor('user/login','Login');
    echo anchor('user/signup','Signup');                        
}

echo '&nbsp;' . anchor(base_url(),'Home');
?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marian for the great help. It is so so close to what I need. The only problem now that I don't know how to set this code in the buttons individually so they show or hide based on a user logged in/out.

Answer (score 1):

If you use sessions for being logged in

```
if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
    //echo links
}
```

make sure to unset() all your $_SESSION vars on logout

Comment: Thanks @Makura, what variable shoudl I use in this case?? any is fine?? or user based var? ok, how about if I want this to happen at the button link, how do I do that??

Comment: Any variable that your login script uses, if not sure use $_SESSION without a var

Comment: it turned out that using tank_auth session function solves the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question, because if you wrote the login system or can know when a user is logged in programmatically... there really should be no question. You can either load different views from the controller based on this "logged in" variable, or pass the variable to your view that is basically $displayLogin... if that is true, display the login information, if not, don't.

Would need to know more about your setup to provide more useful information obviously.

Comment: I made some modification to my original question so it should be clear now, I guess. Thanks, mate.