# How to change the login button to logout when user loggs in via iframe form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have not been able to find a close enough answer to this question to find a solution that works.

I am working in a custom website, and at various points, the user login status is checked before the user can proceed with the action. If they are not logged in, they are asked to login first, and then they are allowed to proceed. To keep the user experience clean, most of this is done through in-page pop-ups that contain an iframe.

The login functionality is working perfectly, but when the user is done with the action and closes the window, the "login" button still shows, making it appear that they have not logged in. They actually have to refresh the page to see their login status. I would prefer, however, that the login status to appear seamless as well.

Currently, I have the login link contained in a div in the parent page:

```
<div class="top_nav">
    <div class="contest_buttons">
        <div class="c_button bkg_gray c_bottom w_quarter" id="#login_tab">
            <?php echo showif(!empty($_SESSION['userID']),'
                <a href="enter.php?go=logout">Logout</a>','
                <a href="enter.php?go=login&iframe=true&amp;width=450&amp;height=275" rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]">Login</a>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="c_button bkg_gray c_bottom w_quarter" id="#profile_tab">
            <?php echo showif(!empty($_SESSION['userID']),'
                <a href="profile.php">My Profile</a>','
                <a href="enter.php?go=register&iframe=true&amp;width=550&amp;height=450" rel="prettyPhoto[iframe]">Register</a>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="c_button bkg_gray c_bottom w_half">
            <a href="http://waynedailynews.com/" target="_blank">Wayne Daily News</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The closest I have gotten to anything that could work is:

```
$('#login_tab', window.parent.document).html('<a href="enter.php?go=logout">Logout</a>');
```

I'm not really sure where to go from there.

At the least, I want the `#login_tab` to read "Logout" when login has completed, but being able to update the `#profile_tab` to read "My Profile" would be great as well.

I am a PHP programmer that is just dabbling in JS and jQuery so far, so even pointing me in the right direction might be helpful. :)

---

I found something that shows some promise. It's not as clean as I would like, but this code seems like it might hold a solution...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(
    {
     callback: function(){
       document.location.reload(true);
    }                       
   })
});
</script>
```

Because I am using PrettyPhoto to create the popups and iframes, I may be able to integrate a method or call another script that would handle my needs and it would occur on the event that the window is closed by the user.

What would it take to make something work this way?

Comment: Events handled within an iFrame are only handled within that iFrame, and are not transferable (As far as I'm aware, I hate iFrames)

Try using a pop-up window from within the site itself rather than a new window. I see you're using jQuery, so use jQuery UI for a modal box that holds the login form. And process the form using Ajax. Then you can change the button with jQuery.

Comment: @KalebKlein You can target functions in the parent window as long as cross-site security rules are not violated.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer to avoid iFrames as much as possible. And that's why I added that statement in parentheses. :)

Comment: The login-only functionality would work fine in ajax, as @KalebKlein suggested, but processing the actions involves a lot more, so to keep users on the same page, I used iframes. This is where I am having trouble with the cross window jquery statement. I think the above could work, but I am not sure how to fire it or to verify what is and isn't working. The solution to iframes is to build the whole site around ajax, but I don't have the skill to do that yet, and my deadline doesn't afford me the time to learn it at that level. :(

Comment: @skrilled, how do I check the cross-site security rules?

Comment: Simple. Usally, a session is set when a new form is loaded. This sessions contains a randomly generated "token." The form will also have a hidden field with this token on it. When the form is submitted, the token from the form is checked with that of the session set by the website. If the tokens match, the form is ready to process. If they don't match, it's likely a bot or hacker is attempting to submit a bogus form. This is knows as Cross Site Request Forgery checking.

Comment: @user3447524 Here is a good tutorial series on Ajax with JQuery and PHP: [YouTube Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-5Ce-KC-noc6DKJlPnT09cPYexqx7FsB)

Comment: @skrilled. I looked up more info on the cross-site security rules, and my methods should fit within the rules with no problem. My iframe sources from the same folder at the same domain using http on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could accomplish this.

You could have the login button on the page(s) inside iframe.?

or You could create the html for the 2 buttons inside php vars and call through said button links.?

However I would try using JS & CSS, check out this simple example of Button state switching.
http://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/

After reading your latest comments,  Maybe try to create login buttons depending on session state.

eg:

```
        if( !isset($_SESSION) ){
           //echo login links here
        }
```

also don't forget to use

```
session_start();
```

in the page shown in iframe.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions. I looked at the tutorial you pointed to, and I have been doing that in another context for several months. It's a cool, simple trick. :) However, in this case, I have to set the inner HTML to something different based on the $_SESSION state. I have PHP code (shown above) that does that during a standard page load.

Comment: For the AJAX part, I want the button in the parent window to change based on a $_SESSION state change initiated in a child iframe. This appears to be a much more complicated job. The best I can tell, the jquery snippet I included in the question might do the job, but I need a framework for initiating the code to check the $_SESSION state and fire that line of code when a login occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer, also check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585996/hide-registration-and-login-buttons-when-a-user-logged-in

Comment: I have done that. :) Using PHP, I have the tabs set up to show various things based on the user's location in the site and the sate of the website. When the user visits another page after logging in, the tabs automatically show the correct links. The issue is where someone logs in when performing an in-page task (in this case, voting on contest entries) and does not leave the page. They are, in fact, logged in, but the links that should display after login won't appear until they leave/refresh the page. I'm wanting an ajax solution that works in that case as well.