# 'Login' value for non logged user and 'Log Out' value for logged in user

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a 'Login' call to action javascript button. My button is working with javascript for to action login and registration. The button code has a value called Login. So the button is always displaying the Login text as a button name all time.

**I want-**

- Logged out users/visitors will see the button name 'Login'
- Logged in users will see the button name 'Log Out' with log out
  action.

Can you please fix by editing my code?

See my code:

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();"><aside id="sidebar-contact_page_sidebar" class="sidebar large-3 small-12 columns">
```

Comment: editing html won't solve this issue

Comment: So what should I do in order to accomplish it?

Comment: When you login the user is it a standard Wordpress login?

Comment: yes, it call the standard login page as a javascript pop up. Button is working fine itself for login and registration. But I want the new functionality based on my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721614/how-to-change-login-and-logout-links-dynamically-in-html-page-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512968/how-to-change-the-login-button-to-logout-when-user-loggs-in-via-iframe-form

Answer (score 2):

if you use this small piece of php code around your login button, it will use different code/show a different button when the user is logged in or is not logged in.

Please note the changed values and the echoed strings above button echo

see wordpress codex reference link for more information
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'user is logged in, show logout button';
        echo '<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Logout" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();"><aside id="sidebar-contact_page_sidebar" class="sidebar large-3 small-12 columns">';
    } else {
        echo 'user is not logged in, show login button';
        echo '<input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();"><aside id="sidebar-contact_page_sidebar" class="sidebar large-3 small-12 columns">';
    }
?>
```

Comment: if this is what you where searching for, please set it as accepted answer